# NullPointer at OnDestroy

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, ondestroy

I'm having an issue that only Crashlytics shown me and my team, I can't reproduce it on my tests devices. It seens that the method onDestroy() is throwing a "NullPointerException".

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    UsersOnRoom.removeAll();
    try {
        audioManager.removeAudioFiles();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

[image]

RoomBaseActivity extends another Activity, that has no implementation of onDestroy().

I have no ideia what's is causing it.

Comment: It should be pretty obvious. Depending on which line is 598, either `UsersOnRoom` or `audioManager` is `null`. Figure out why that could be and/or check for them being `null` before running that code. Also, there is no guarantee that `onDestroy()` will be called when you expect so you may want to move that code to `onPause()` or `finish()` depending on what you need.

Comment: Maybe, it is happening because in case of exception, super.onDestroy(); is called twice... try to remove super.onDestroy(); from catch block since it will be called in the end of the function

Comment: @codeMagic both classes aren't null, and it's not obvious, that I can assure you.

Comment: @Guilherme P maybe, it's a good ideia to remove the super.OnDestroy(). let's see what happens. The thing is, this crash doesn't happen in any of my test devices, and I have a lot of it.